# PHP calculate with special chars

Tags: php, mysql, math, formatting

I'm working on a function that's getting data from a MySQL database and then it should calculate it. I've got the function like I want it, but my only problem is that my value in the database looks like:

> €12.345,67

But PHP thinks the dots are commas. So with the formatting my result looks like:

> 25.000,00 + 40.000,00 =65.00

How it should look like:

> 25.000,00 + 40.000,00 = 65.000,00

I've already tried following parameter:

```
str_replace(',', '.', $value1);
```

It didn't work, so I'm asking if someone has a clue how to do this.

My code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","DB-Nane");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Fahrzeugverkauf WHERE Fahrzeugkonto = 2");
$rahmen = 230000;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $total3 = $row['EKBrutto'];
    $test +=$total3;
    $belastung= $rahmen - $test;


}
//$res1 = 

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<?php echo "Verfügbarer Rahmen: " .$rahmen;?>     <br> 
<?php echo "Belastung: " .$test;?>     <br> 
    <?php echo "Verbliebenes Guthaben: " .$belastung;?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `number_format()` function?

Comment: Not yet, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Try it:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%(#10n', $number) . "\n";
// ($        1,234.57)
```

from:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php

Comment: It's kinda working, my only problem is how can i do commas and dots at the same time?

Comment: If you remove all dots firstly and after replace the comma by dot it certanly will also work: str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $value1));

Comment: But I still think if you are using currency type at your database you should use the money_format or another function to work with currency data format... If your database is varchar you should change to work as currency or at least some numeric type as float.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Number Formatter Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) like,

```
<?php 
   $a = new \NumberFormatter("it-IT", \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY); 
   echo $a->formatCurrency(12345, "USD") . "<br>"; // outputs $ 12.345,00 and it is formatted using the italian notation (comma as decimal separator) 
?>
```